# Можно ли отслеживать данные в бд и манипулировать ими при наступлении какого-то события?

Tags: javascript, node.js, база-данных, mongodb, nestjs

Всем привет. Я делаю один проект, в котором для серверной части использую nest js и mongo db. И, на сервере есть возможно добавлять события с временными метками. По типу, название, описание, картинка + время существования. И, я не знаю, существует ли какая-либо возможность отслеживать это время и удалять или как-то скрывать(при помощи соответствующих полей в моделях) события с уже истекшим "сроком годности"? Или же достаточно проверять это время на стороне клиента и просто отображать только "свежие" события?

Comment: Добавить [фильтр](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) по типу "выбрать события, где дата начала <= now()".

Comment: Не не, там смысл именно в том, что событие не вечное, как бы. В какой-то момент оно закончиться. Я просто отображаю все активные на данный момент. А вот что делать с теми, которые уже закончились я не знаю. Хотелось бы, мб, как-то удалять их из бд или тип того.

Comment: Чтобы база монги не расла, есть 2 способа. 1. сделать удаление таких записей по расписанию, самый простой вариант - cron, который запускает `mongo --eval "... запрос на удаление устаревших записей"`. Либо на ноде поставить модуль типа node-cron или сделать замыкание setInterval которое будет выполнять это действие. 2. сделать [caped коллекцию](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) - если она подходит для вашего кейса.

Comment: Спасибо. Это уже более подходящие решения)

Comment: В mongo есть TTL индексы, как вариант использовать их.